# Smart card / auditable access for rack KVM tray

Tags: authentication, smartcard, keyboard-video-mouse

Is there such a thing as a KVM Tray for a standard 19" rack whose use can be validated by a smartcard (or some other auditable authentication method)?

It looks like we have a security requirement where just because users have a key to the rack doesn't mean they will be allowed to use the console inside the rack, and rather than just lock the console (and keep track of who has keys), we would prefer to be able to audit the actual user that was attached at the KVM.

(It's worth mentioning that I'm aware of the [Raritan devices](http://www.raritan.com.au/products/kvm-over-ip/dominion-kx-ii/), but they surely can't be the only ones)

<sub>(If these things existed, I don't think half of the tratoirs that somehow manage to infiltrate CTU on the [TV show 24](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0285331/) would ever get away with anything)</sub>

Comment: Sheesh, sounds expensive. :) I assume that just granting/controlling access via iLOM/DRAC/etc. isn't an option then?

Comment: @ErikA - yeah, that will be controlled for remote users, but that doesn't apply to local console users. Our M1000e chassis just allow anyone to walk up and connect to the local consoles. I'm not too worried about the price; I'm not paying for it!

Comment: Well, I certainly know of no such thing, but I'm interested to see what becomes of this question.

Comment: The console users can't or don't have to login at the console?

Comment: @UniSoft - some of the devices in the rack don't have any authentication - legacy devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many ports do you need?
The only other HW KVM with Smart Card support I know of is the AdderView Secure.
But they only exists in 2 and 4 port switches.
http://www.adder.com/uk/secure-kvm-switches.aspx

How about a self build KVM, using a Smart Card terminal like a SunRay, and connect to the KVM from there?

Comment: Their 4-port version actually looks perfect for our scenario. Unfortunately the contract was cancelled about a week ago so I won't get a chance to actually use the devices, but it's good to know for next time. That SunRay idea had crossed my mind, but I'm ultimately looking for a Plug and Play solution.